# Express-Validator using Regex for request body fields

Tags: regex, express

My POST request sends form fields with names similar to `email-0`, `email-1`, `email-2` to the Express back-end, but the exact number of such fields may vary. How do I use the Validation API to check these fields when I don't know all the actual names in advance. I tried using a Regex  as such: `body('\\^email-[0-9]*$\\', 'Must be valid email.').isLength({min: 5}).trim(),` but so far I haven't gotten it to work.

Am I not escaping the Regex properly, or is it simply not possible to use Regex in this way? If not, is there another solution to what I'm aiming for, i.e. when we  don't know all the exact  field names in advance? (I read the explanation on Wildcards in the [official Express-Validator documentation](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/wildcards.html), but these don't seem applicable here, or did I miss something?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this works:

```
        (req,res,next)=> {
            Object.keys(req.body).filter(fld=>fld.match(new RegExp('^email\\S*-[0-9]*$'))).forEach(fld=>
                body(fld, 'Must be valid email.').isLength({min: 5}).trim());
                next();
        }
```

In place of `body('\\^email-[0-9]*$\\', 'Must be valid email.').isLength({min: 5}).trim()`